# Can I combine forcing a variable to be null with a ?? operator?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public List<Phrase> GetViewablePhrases(MO mode, int pts = 0, bool force = false)
{
    if (force == true) App.selectedPhrases = null;
    App.selectedPhrases = App.selectedPhrases ?? App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();
```

I don't really understand usage of the ?? but I assume that it is saying if the `App.selectedPhrases` is null then get new phrases and otherwise use the existing.

My function also has a force option so what I did was use this line:

```
if (force == true) App.selectedPhrases = null;
```

Is there a way that these two lines could be combined:

```
if (force == true) App.selectedPhrases = null;
        App.selectedPhrases = App.selectedPhrases ?? App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();
```

Comment: App.selectedPhrases = (force ? null : App.selectedPhrases) ?? App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would concentrate on readability: you want to get new phrases *if* either `force` is true or we don't have any at the moment:

```
if (force || App.selectedPhrases == null)
{
    App.selectedPhrases = App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();
}
```

While you *can* do this in a single assignment statement using the conditional ?: operator and the null coalescing operator, I think it's clearer to write it with an `if` statement to make it clear that in other cases, you're not changing anything.

Comment: I also up-voted this answer, but don't you think it's kind of being resistant towards features like ternary or null conditional operators?

Comment: @rad: No, absolutely not. Where you want to *unconditionally* take an action, but with a *value* that's computed in a conditional way, then both the conditional ?: operator and the null coalescing operator are useful. Where you want to *conditionally* take an action, an `if` statement is the most natural way of expressing that, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I would use this code

```
    if (force || App.selectedPhrases == null) {
        App.selectedPhrases = App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();
    }

    return App.selectedPhrases;
```

// edit: oh @rad was faster then me

Answer (score 2):

Even though the below will solve what you want I agree with Jon about the readability as you should go with his answer.

---

One way is to use the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
App.selectedPhrases = (force ? null : App.selectedPhrases) ?? App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();
```

As for the [`??` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
App.selectedPhrases = (force || App.selectedPhrases == null) ? App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases() : App.selectedPhrases;
```

Comment: And what is `App.selectedPhrases` is null? In your version the result will be null whereas in the question it will not